# How to create a submenu with radio buttons in Android?

Tags: android, contextmenu

I have a problem in a simple case (at least, it looks like so). I need to create a submenu for a context menu dynamically and provide each item with a radiobox. I made a lot of trials. When I call `menu.setGroupCheckable(0, true, true)`, where 0 is by default the menu itself, it displays radio buttons to the right on every menu item as expected, but I need this for submenu. So I have the following code:

```
SubMenu sub = menu.addSubMenu(R.string.name);
int count = 1000;
for(String e : someList)
{
  MenuItem item = sub.add(1, count, count, e);
  count++;
}
menu.setGroupCheckable(1, true, true);
```

In this case I don't see neither radioboxes, nor checkboxes in the submenu. Then I wrote the following code:

```
SubMenu sub = menu.addSubMenu(R.string.name);
int count = 1000;
for(String e : someList)
{
  MenuItem item = sub.add(1, count, count, e);
  item.setCheckable(true);
  count++;
}
menu.setGroupCheckable(1, true, true);
```

This makes the submenu to have a checkbox in every item, and the checkboxes work exclusively, but I want radioboxes, because they look more intuitively for exclusive selection.

So, how can this be accomplished?

Comment: Bear in mind that context menus are fading away, in favor of contextual action modes on the action bar.

Comment: Still applies to the SubMenu that goes with an ActionProvider in the action bar.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found out that groups of menus and submenus are processed separately, that is a group formed in a submenu, should be addressed via the submenu, not via the top-level menu. So the solution is to call:

```
sub.setGroupCheckable(1, true, true);
```

This code works as expected, that is items in the submenu show radiobuttons instead of checkboxes.

Comment: Only works if you call setGroupCheckable after adding the menus

Answer (score 27):

Set the checkableBehavior in xml to single.
Here is some code:

```
<menu>
      <group android:id="@+id/group"
             android:checkableBehavior="single">
             <item android:id="@+id/menu_sort_by_name"
                   android:title="@string/action_sort_by_name"/>
             <item android:id="@+id/menu_sort_by_last_edit"
                   android:title="@string/action_sort_by_last_edit"/>
      </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: In addition, make sure the subitems do not have their checkable attribute set.

Comment: he creates items programmatically